# Android Studio doesn't align multiline chained method calls during live editing

Tags: android-studio, code-formatting, android-studio-2.2

It works when I use code->reformat code. But when I am writing the code it doesn't align the chained method calls.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: If you have some text selected, this reformat only works on selected codes. isn't it the point?

Comment: No, I have the option enabled to align multiline chained method calls in settings. So it should work during live editing also. Other formatting options work.